# CISCO PBX 2811 cannot make local calls

Tags: pbx, cisco-ios

We recently moved our company far enough that we have a new area code. I've setup our network and PBX and everything seems to be working fine except the phones. I can dial long distance numbers (any number not within our new local area code). I cannot dial local numbers (any number within our new area code). I have a feeling it has something to do with changing area codes. Perhaps the CISCO PBX has a call pattern that is trying to add area codes to local numbers (because maybe the CISCO PBX thinks we are still at our old area code)???? Not sure exactly how to fix this issue. I have command line access to the pbx and can use Call Manager Express... There are not settings that jump out at me as an obvious setting to change when doing the "show run" command.

Any help in this area would be very appreciated. I'm hoping there is a simple command line method of changing a call pattern to handle the area code change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem unrelated to the PBX. When we moved offices we were in an area that allowed local calling without using an area code. Our new office location required an area code for all calls, local or long distance. So folks were able to make long distance calls and not local calls. Using the local area code solved the problem but folks were used to not dialing the area code for local calls. So I setup the PBX to append the local area code for local numbers (7 digit numbers).